# How do I add an item to the Bootstrap Simple Carousel on Drupal 8?

Tags: blocks, bootstrap-theme

I'm having problems configuring the Bootstrap Simple Carousel module on Drupal 8.

I see that I can add carousel items at /admin/structure/bootstrap_simple_carousel and I've created the carousel block and given it a region.

But how do I get the items to display in the carousel block? At the moment it's just an empty block. I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Thank you in advance for help.